# What application pool does the Bin folder use?

Tags: .net, application-pool

We have a classic asp website which requires a .NET exporting component.  We have installed a part of the plugin to highcharts/HighchartsExport.aspx (this is the file we call to run it) and the required dlls into the /Bin folder as instructed.

Everything works but I want this .net plugin to run in it's own application pool as we seem to get getting the occasional application crash/recycle and I want to isolate it.

I can use "Convert to application" on the "/highcharts" folder and change the app pool there but what about the /Bin folder.

Obviously I could separate the component onto a completely separate sub-domain but I'd prefer to keep this as one site (+I'm curious about how this works.)

Comment: what is the base version of .net framework for HighchartsExport modules?

Answer (score 0):

The `bin` folder runs under the configured application pool for the application it is part of.

Comment: so I need to use convert to application (and set the new app pool) on the bin folder as well as the highcharts one?

Comment: @DavidMeagor - I would leave the `bin` folder alone, unless you get errors.